# Power::infy: "Infinite expression 1/0. encountered" (ODE Solution using NDSolve)

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

While solving the following ode,

```
Eq1 = f'''[x] - f'[x]*f'[x] + f[x]*f''[x] - K1*(2  f'[x]* f'''[x] - f[x]* f''''[x] - f''[x]*f''[x]) - f'[x] == 0
```

with the conditions

```
deqsys = {Eq1, f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 1, f'[N1] == 0, f''[N1] == 0}
```

and

```
K1 = 1.0;
```

Here `N1=2`, which is an approximation of `N1=Infinity`. It does not sound right but even for `N1=2`, I am unable to obtain a solution using `NDSolve`.

Now calling upon the numerical solver

```
NDSolve[deqsys, f, {x, 0, N1}]
```

I'm facing this persistent error,

> Power::infy: "Infinite expression 1/0. encountered."

I have no idea, whether there is something wrong with the syntax, or the ode is a stiff one, or there is no solution to it?

Comment: Try `Solve[Eq1, f''''[x]]` and think about what happens at the initial condition.

Comment: @Michael E2 I see your point. But when I try to solve the same equation with maple, I get solution to ode for negative values of 'K1' only.

Comment: Your initial conditions always contain `f[0] == 0`? This sort of singularity has come up on this site several times, and it each case the suggested solution is to change it to something like `f[10^-6] == 10^-6`.  In some cases I think it should be possible mathematically to specify an initial value for the highest order derivative, but I'm not sure if `NDSolve` will let you.  Any clue as to what step Maple takes initially?

Comment: Well, simply using maple `dsolve` just handle it. As for as the background stuff is concern behind it, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way that gets fairly close.  Perhaps further tweaking could improve the result.

```
Block[{K1 = 1},
 {sol} = NDSolve[deqsys, f, {x, 0, 2}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" ->
       {f[0] == 10^-4, f'[0] == 1, f''[0] == 0.1, f'''[0] == -0.1}, 
     Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"}]
 ]
```

This avoids the singularity when `f[x] == 0` by starting the boundary condition `f[0]` close to zero.  Then the shooting method tries to get the initial conditions so that the boundary conditions are satisfied.  They get close, but not close enough for the default `NDSolve` measure:

> `NDSolve::berr:` There are significant errors `{0.00267854,-4.06858*10^-11,0.0000859285,0.000110968}` in the boundary value residuals. Returning the best solution found. >>

```
Plot[{f[x], f'[x], f''[x]} /. First[sol] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can try raising `"MaxIterations"` higher than `100`.

Comment: Methinks one could even be bold and do `f[0] == $MachineEpsilon`.

Answer (score 2):

Once again, surprisingly, finite difference method (FDM) seems to help in this case. (This is against my impression that FDM will also fail if `"Shooting"` method fails to solve a boundary value problem. ) I'll use [`pdetoae`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the generation of difference equation:

```
K1 = 1;
lb = 0; rb = 10/100;
Eq1 = f'''[x] - f'[x] f'[x] + f[x] f''[x] - 
    K1 (2 f'[x] f'''[x] - f[x] f''''[x] - f''[x] f''[x]) - f'[x] == 0;
set = {Eq1, f[lb] == 0, f'[lb] == 1, f'[rb] == 0, f''[rb] == 0};
points = 300;
difforder = 6;
grid = Array[# &, points, {lb, rb}];
(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this code piece,
   please find it in the link above. *)
ptoa = pdetoae[f[x], grid, difforder];
ae = MapAt[#[[3 ;; -3]] &, ptoa@set, {{1}}];
var = # /@ grid &@f // Flatten;
initialguess = 10^-2;
sollst = FindRoot[ae, {#, initialguess} & /@ var, 
    MaxIterations -> Infinity]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {12.972383, Null} *)
func = ListInterpolation[sollst[[All, -1]], grid, InterpolationOrder -> difforder];
Plot[func[x], {x, lb, rb}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Values of `rb` i.e. right boundary, initial guess of function value i.e. `initialguess` are determined by trial and error.

Error check:

```
Subtract @@@ set[[2 ;;]] /. f -> func
(* {0., -5.55112*10^-16, -3.017*10^-14, -7.42259*10^-10} *)
(* Residual error: *)
Plot[set[[1, 1]] /. f -> func // Evaluate, {x, lb, rb}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may feel the residual error is large, but if you enlarge `points`, you'll see the graph of `func[x]` is stable and the residual error significantly decreases.